# Correct format of TypeScript typing definition files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I've been learning TypeScript recently and have been puzzling a bit over how node modules should be imported into a TypeScript project.  I find that the documentation is a bit weak on these issues but maybe that is just me.

In particular, I had trouble with the DefinitelyTyped typing definitions for the [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/) library.  Whether I used the triple-slash reference or added `mathjs.d.ts` to `tsconfig.json` the emitted js never seemed to include the require statement for this particular module.  I found a solution that seems to work for me but am wondering if I have missed something.  Original and my changes to the typing definition file are here.  Is this issue simply that the definitions file was out of date with most recent TypeScript?

**.d.ts from repository**

```
declare var math: mathjs.IMathJsStatic;

declare namespace mathjs {

    type MathArray = number[]|number[][];
    type MathType = number|BigNumber|Fraction|Complex|Unit|MathArray|Matrix;
    type MathExpression = string|string[]|MathArray|Matrix;

    export interface IMathJsStatic {

        <Bunch of Definitions>
    }
}
```

**my changes**

```
 declare var math: mathjs_namespace.IMathJsStatic;

    declare namespace mathjs_namespace {

        type MathArray = number[]|number[][];
        type MathType = number|BigNumber|Fraction|Complex|Unit|MathArray|Matrix;
        type MathExpression = string|string[]|MathArray|Matrix;

        export interface IMathJsStatic {

            <Bunch of Definitions>
        }
    }

declare module "mathjs" {
    export = math;
}
```